# Magento2 - Admin keeps on loading

Tags: magento2, custom-theme, slowbackend

Why Magento2 Admin Panel is too much slow and keeps on loading ?

[image: slow]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hope this three commands will solve your problem

```
php bin/magento se:up
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento s:d:c
```

also enable the cache

```
php bin/magento cache:enable
```

or else try uninstall the theme

```
php bin/magento theme:uninstall
```

Comment: Enable the cache worked

Answer (score 0):

whether you made any changes at backend code regarding functionality?

Comment: I have added custom theme at the backend now want to activate it through admin but it keeeps on loading

Answer (score 0):

Enable caches.
This can make your work more productive. :)

Comment: I have newly installed magento and uploaded a custom theme

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
rm -rf var/cache/ generated/code pub/static/frontend pub/static/adminhtml
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/
```

This will fix the problem